# Completion statement closure error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, closures, skaction

I'm trying to make this SKAction to run with a completion, but, believe me, I can't find a way to do this simple completion. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if it is just a bug (I'm using Xcode 7 beta 2).

This is the code, I have tried everything but the completion returns an error.

```
let move = SKAction.moveTo(ship.position, duration: 4)
    meteor.runAction(move, completion: {
                self.meteor.zRotation = 3 * M_PI / 180
    })
```

If someone can help would be very nice, thanks!

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot invoke 'runAction' with an argument list of type '(SKAction, completion: () -> _)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are getting is not that great. You need to wrap `M_PI` in a CGFloat. Like this, `CGFloat(M_PI)`